# zend1 query converted to plain mysqli?

Tags: zend-framework, mysqli

I have this zend framework 1 query which looks like this:

```
function getNumberOfNewPlayer() {
    global $db, $start_date, $end_date;
    $data = $db->select()
            ->from(array('c' => 'casino_israel.Network'),array('count(*) as total'))
            ->where('c.Date > ?', $start_date)
            ->where('c.Date < ?', $end_date)
            ->query()->fetch();         
    return $data['total'];  
}
```

How would it look line in plain mysqli?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = $db->select()
            ->from(array('c' => 'casino_israel.Network'),array('count(*) as total'))
            ->where('c.Date > ?', $start_date)
            ->where('c.Date < ?', $end_date);

echo $data->__toString();
```